# Apache Ignite: how to insert into table with IDENTITY key (SQL Server)

Tags: ignite

I have a table in SQL Server where the primary key is autogenerated (identity column), i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE TableName 
(
     table_id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
     some_field VARCHAR(20),

     PRIMARY KEY (table_id)
);
```

Since `table_id` is an autogenerated column, when I implemented the `SqlFieldQuery` `INSERT` clause I do not set any argument to `table_id`:

```
sql = new SqlFieldsQuery("INSERT INTO TableName (some_field) VALUES (?)");
cache.query(sql.setArgs("str");
```

However at runtime I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.cache.CacheException: class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.IgniteSQLException: Failed to execute DML statement [stmt=INSERT INTO TableName (some_field) VALUES (?), params=["str"]]
>
> at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.query(IgniteCacheProxy.java:807)
>   at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.query(IgniteCacheProxy.java:765)
>   ...
>   Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.IgniteSQLException: Failed to execute DML statement [stmt=INSERT INTO TableName (some_field) VALUES (?), params=["str"]]
>
> at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.queryDistributedSqlFields(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1324)
>   at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$5.applyx(GridQueryProcessor.java:1815)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$5.applyx(GridQueryProcessor.java:1813)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.lang.IgniteOutClosureX.apply(IgniteOutClosureX.java:36)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.executeQuery(GridQueryProcessor.java:2293)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.querySqlFields(GridQueryProcessor.java:1820)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.query(IgniteCacheProxy.java:795)
>           ... 5 more
>       Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Key is missing from query
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.dml.UpdatePlanBuilder.createSupplier(UpdatePlanBuilder.java:331)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.dml.UpdatePlanBuilder.planForInsert(UpdatePlanBuilder.java:196)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.dml.UpdatePlanBuilder.planForStatement(UpdatePlanBuilder.java:82)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.DmlStatementsProcessor.getPlanForStatement(DmlStatementsProcessor.java:438)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.DmlStatementsProcessor.updateSqlFields(DmlStatementsProcessor.java:164)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.DmlStatementsProcessor.updateSqlFieldsDistributed(DmlStatementsProcessor.java:222)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.queryDistributedSqlFields(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1321)
>           ... 11 more

This is how I planned to implement the insertion because it seemed more tedious to get the max `table_id` from the cache, increment and insert. I thought I could omit the `table_id` from the insert and let SQL Server insert the pk, but it doesn't seem to work like this.

Can you please tell me how this should typically be implemented in Ignite? I checked the ignite-examples, unfortunately the examples are too simple (i.e. fixed keys only, like 1 or 2).

Moreover, how does Ignite support the use of sequences?

I am using ignite-core 2.2.0. Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's true that as for now autoincrement fields are not supported.
As an option, you could generate IDs manually via for example [Ignite's ID generator](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/id-generator).

Comment: I'm not sure how viable this is entirely, but you could also use a UUID as the primary key. And you probably want to use something like an ordered/sequential one to reduce the performance hit of using UUIDs as PKs: https://github.com/f4b6a3/uuid-creator

Answer (score 5):

Ignite doesn't support identity columns [1] yet.

It may be non-obviuos, but Ignite SQL layer is built on top of key value store which can be backed by other CacheStore. Your SQL query will never go though to CacheStore as is.

Ignite internals will execute your query, save data in cache and only then update will be propagated to CacheStore which will create a new SQL query for your SQL server.

So, Ignite need the identity column value (actually a key) be known before data saved in cache.

[1] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-5625